# Loop across columns, if range in column contains string, apply formula to first cell in column

Tags: excel, vba

I have columns that contain strings. I am trying to write a macro that will go across columns and look at the rows in the column to determine if the string is present. If the string is present, I need to apply a formula to the first cell in the column.  I've tried a few different methods, but no luck. I don't have formal vba training, but I enjoy learning, so I appreciate your help!

The word I am searching for usually shows up in rows 4-15, which is why I am searching those rows specifically, but it would be great to expand it.

```
lastCol = nWs.UsedRange.Column + nWs.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1••••ˇˇˇˇ
columnLetter = Split(Cells(1, lastCol).Address, "$")(1)

For i = 3 To lastCol
If Range(i & "4:" & i & "15").Value = "name" Then Range(i & "1").Formula = "=1+1"
Next i
```

Another attempt:

```
    Set AB = nWs.Range("D1:" & columnLetter & "16").Cells
K = 1
For Each r In AB
    If InStr(1, r.Value, "name") > 0 Then
        Range(K & "1").Formula = "=1+1"
        K = K + 1
    End If
    Next
```

This is interesting and accounts for the range issue, but the formula 1+1 result does not appear above columns that contain the word "name."  What happens is at the top of the very last column, the word "false" appears:
      Dim rng As Range

```
    Set rng = nWs.Range("D1:" & columnLetter & "15")
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        nWs.Range(columnLetter & "1").Value = IIf(InStr(1, cell, "name"), "=1+1", "False")
    Next
```

I believe the issue is that I am searching a range? I definitely appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need to update the...

1. sheet name for variable `ws` (Currently using `Sheet1`)
2. `LC` variable set to use the row number that will help you identify your last used column (Currently using `Row 2`)
3. `LR` variable set to use the column index that will help you identify your last used row (Currently using `Column 1`)
4. text you are trying to find for the variable `FindMe`

*Each line that needs to be updated is marked in code with `'<-- UPDATE!`*

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Col_Hunter()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- UPDATE!
Dim LC As Long, LR As Long, i as Long, Found As Range, FindMe As String

LC = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column '<-- UPDATE!
LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '<-- UPDATE!
FindMe = "name" '<-- UPDATE!

For i = 1 To LC
    Set Found = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, i), ws.Cells(LR, i)).Find(FindMe)
        If Not Found Is Nothing Then
            ws.Cells(1, i).Formula = "=1+1"
        End If
    Set Found = Nothing
Next i

End Sub
```

---

You may also want to update some of the available options on the `Range.Find` method that I am making use of. You can find out how this can be tweaked to fit your exact needs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

Comment: This is definitely awesome code! I really appreciate your help - it certainly provides me lots of guidance going forward. Unfortunately, it didn't work with my data, so I'm not sure what the issue is but I will investigate further and do some test code. Do I need to reset the i? so end the for loop with i = i+1?

Comment: No. The `Next i` does that automatically. What didn't work? Are you looking for an exact match or looking for the name inside the cell with other text? The code is currently set up for exact match. The link I provided at the bottom provides info on how to change this

Comment: The formula did not apply. I created some sample data to run it on to see if maybe my existing data had wonky spaces in the text I was searching for, but no dice. It is an exact match.